# How to guarantee a seamless transition from a nearly expired provisioning file and a new one?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

**Context:** A provisioning profile(PP) is nearly expired. The distribution certificate linked to it, will not expire for the next 2 years. The corresponding app is distributed over a MDM. All i read about renewing a PP is also including renewing the distribution certificate. But i just want to extend the PP with as little effort as possible.

**Approaches:** Either i would just press the "Generate" (on apple developer site while editing the PP) without changing anything or i would create a new one besides this one with same settings.

**Questions:** Which approach do you recommend? Is there a way, that i don't have to reinstall the app? What happens if i update this PP? Will the app run until the old PP is expired and then i have to install the new app with new PP?

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the certificate is still good for a while, the best approach is to simply generate a new provisioning profile.  Your existing deployments of the app will not be affected (as long as you don't revoke the certificate) because the existing profile is technically still valid until it expires.

Then, before the old profile expires, you have two options.

1. You can re-build the app with the new provisioning profile and push to the devices with your MDM solution.  This will install the app **AND** the new provisioning profile on the devices. The app doesn't need to have changed - you are just using it to carry the payload of the new provisioning profile.  The app will then work until the new provisioning profile expires (and you'll repeat this process next year).
2. If your MDM solution offers the ability to push the provisioning profile to your devices directly, take your new provisioning profile and deploy it to all the devices with the app.  Once you have done this, the app will continue to run after the original, embedded provisioning profile has expired, because all iOS cares about is if there is a valid provisioning profile for the app ID **on the device**.  No need to re-build the app, so this is preferable if there is no other reason to update the app.

Note that when your certificate expires, however, you will need to rebuild (or at least re-sign) the apps and redeploy them to the devices, so there will be no easy fix of just pushing a new provisioning profile when that happens. Plan ahead and give yourself enough time before the cert expires to make sure all necessary apps are re-built and redeployed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will test it and come back =)